# Defining Application Constants in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know a clean way of defining Application Constants in Codeigniter. I don't want to change any native file of codeigniter. Hence I don't want to define it in `application/config/constants.php` as when I need to migrate to newer version of code-igniter I will not be able to copy the native files of codeigniter directly.

I created a file `application/config/my_constants.php` and defined my constants there. 'define('APP_VERSION', '1.0.0');'

I loaded it using `$this->load->config('my_constants');`

But I am getting a error

`Your application/config/dv_constants.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.`

Please suggest me a clean way of defining application level constants in code-igniter.

Comment: Please follow the guide it will help you http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Comment: It's not very useful, because, as it says in the guide, codeigniter will merge your file into the constants array, so you'll get the same result and openning one more file than usual, so it will be slower.

Comment: Any files in application folders are for you to edit. Just avoid changing anything in system folder.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Not using `application/config/constants.php` is nonsense! That is the **only place** you *should* be putting your constants. Don't change the files in `system` if you are worried about upgrading.

Comment: The reason I avoid using `application/config/constants.php` for my custom application constants is I wanted to keep my custom application constants seperate from the General Code-Igniter defined constant.

I am keeping my custom config parameters in a separate file `application/config/my_config.php` and not mixing it with `application/config/config.php`

In the same line I wanted to keep my custom application constants in seperate file. For now I am going to use `application/config/constants.php` to define my constants. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can include_once 'my_constants.php' from constants.php to keep those files separate.

Answer (score 4):

just a complete answer. (None of the answers show how to use the constants that were declared)

The process is simple:

1. Defining a constant. Open `config/constants.php` and add the following line:

   `define('SITE_CREATOR', 'John Doe')`
2. use this constant in another file using:

   `$myVar = 'This site was created by '.SITE_CREATOR.' Check out my GitHub Profile'`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `define()`, your my_constants.php file should look something like this:

```
$config['app_version'] = '1.0.0';
```

Be careful with naming the array key though, you don't want to conflict with anything.

If you need to use `define()`, I would suggest doing it in the main index.php file, though you will still need to use `APP_VERSION` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
    config file (system/application/config/config.php) to set configuration related variables.

    Or use 

    constant file (system/application/config/constants.php) to store site preference constants.


  =======================
  DEFINE WHAT YOU WANT
  =======================
  $config['index_page'] = 'home';
  $config['BASEPATH'] = 'PATH TO YOUR HOST';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/56981/

Define variable in to constants & add value on array

```
$ORDER_STATUS  = array('0'=>'In Progress','1'=>'On Hold','2'
                 =>'Awaiting Review','3'=>'Completed','4'
                 =>'Refund Requested','5'=>'Refunded');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal by adding constants to your own config file, such as `my_config.php`.

You would save this file in the `application/config` folder, like this:
`application/config/my_config.php`.

It is very common to have a separate config file for each application you write, so this would be easy to maintain and be understood by other CI programmers.

You can instruct CI to autoload this file or you can load it manually, as needed. See the CI manual on "Config class".

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest that you use composer.json to autoload your own Constants.php file, like this:

[image]